# Javascript Canvas Selector

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm not sure whether this is something that is possible in Javascript, I'm fairly sure it will be.

I have a client that sells canvas prints online. They need a solution that will enable customers to firstly select an image, then a color, then a size, and for it all to appear on a 'mock' canvas all on the same page.

[image: example]

This will then proceed to a paypal cart checkout.

Does anybody know of a way to do this, or could point me in the direction of a website that I can walk through this with?

Thanks!
Jonna

Comment: This will be possible with a `<canvas>` element on which you can dynamically draw. However, please show us the website code you already have.

Comment: I have no code at the moment, I'm starting from scratch, and I don't know much JS!

I'm not able to post pictures yet, otherwise I would show you.

Comment: Actually I've just uplaoded the image to TinyPic - you can view the layout I mean here - http://tinypic.com/r/148pvkx/6

Comment: Start with the HTML/PHP + CSS first. After you have a working site, learn JS and [improve some features to be more dynamic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)

Comment: Thanks, I do actually have the HTML and CSS in place, this feature is the last piece of the website. What I meant was, I don't have any code for starting the feature. I'm not even sure where to start.

If you know of any websites that cover this topic I would be appreciative.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost exactly what Fabric.js, as JavaScript canvas library, was originally made for (well, for shirts): http://fabricjs.com

There are a multitude of other libraries that do similar, but the bottom line is that it is very possible. Have a look at Fabric.js, Kinetic.js, easel.js, and start learning!

Comment: That looks very useful! I'll go take a looksie, thanks very much Simon!

Comment: Hello Simon

Thank you for your post, I took a look at the suggestions, and they look great, but overly complex for what I need. I think I may have put some confusion into the situation, sorry!

When I say canvas, I meant actual canvases, printed to hang on your wall, not so much HTML5 canvases.

All I need it to do is select the animal and colour, and have those selections appear on a box underneath the colours, and have the names of those selections underneath that.

Does that make sense? Sorry for the confusion! Help still much appreciated!! :)